# Comparing many maths fonts

Tags: fonts

I'd like to produce a document comparing all of the different bb (blackboard bold) fonts available in LaTeX. [symbols-a4.pdf](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) gives is what I will assume is a comprehensive list:

[image]

The problem is that three different packages override the `\mathbb` command. I tried to 'save' each version as shown in the following MWE, but to no avail:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\let\bboldbb\mathbb
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\let\amsbb\mathbb

\begin{document}
$\amsbb{N} \bboldbb{N}$
\end{document}
```

Using `\def` in place of `\let` doesn't work either.  How can I use multiple versions of `\mathbb` at once? (And what is wrong with my MWE?)

Comment: You should look at the source file for the Comprehensive List (`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/source/symbols.tex` on TeX Live); look for `\IfStyFileExists` and you'll realize how many tricks the author did for loading all the fonts.

Comment: Depending on the number of usages, you could also consider including an image of the "foreign symbols" by compiling it in a separate `standalone` document.