# Techniques for comparing the shapes of a particular glyph in different fonts

Tags: fonts, symbols

I would like to compare the shape of a particular symbol in many different fonts. Let us assume for the sake of simplicity that the symbol is non-composite, that is it is a glyph straight from a particular font. Let us also assume some default font size (say `10pt`, but it doesn't really matter).

Say I would like to compare all paragraph signs (`\P`) across a number of fonts that are installed by default for (La)TeX. (I would like to find all fonts with a hollow paragraph symbol. With `\usepackage{tgschola,textcomp}` I get a hollow one; the default symbol is a glyph with a filled bowl.)

**What are some techniques, tricks, and caveats for exploring a symbol across fonts?**

I am aware of different font formats, so this question is complex and a bit open-ended. I am also assuming that any answers will need to make simplifying assumptions.

A similar question has in fact been asked: [Comparing many maths fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87104/14996)

Answer (score 9):

You have to know the font family name; here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,textcomp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mm}
 { % #1 = list of families
   % #2 = glyph to test
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \makebox[3em][l]{##1:}
    \group_begin:
    \fontfamily{##1}\selectfont#2\ %
    \fontshape{it}\selectfont#2\ %
    \fontshape{n}\fontseries{bx}\selectfont#2\ %
    \fontshape{it}\selectfont#2
    \group_end:
    \par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\test{cmr,lmr,ptm,qtm,pnc,qcs}{\textparagraph}
\test{cmr,lmr,ptm,qtm,pnc,qcs}{a}
\end{document}
```

[image]